# Shortest-path in a grid using prolog

Tags: prolog, shortest-path, dijkstra

Sorry by the first ask, I'm new at the hood... I did a cleaning on the code. The problem is:
I have a square grid with paths and obstacles. I want to find the shortest path from a point to another. This is part of an artificial intelligence. When the path is too large, I can not see the whole list of points on the bash, but in the game, the character who travels this path, it does not at shortest path. So, my question is, how I can change this code to solve the shortest path. Thank you so much!

```
mov(X1,Y1,X2,Y2):-
   pos(X1,Y1), X2 is X1 , Y2 is Y1+1 ,pos(X2,Y2).
mov(X1,Y1,X2,Y2):-
   pos(X1,Y1), X2 is X1 , Y2 is Y1-1 ,pos(X2,Y2). 
mov(X1,Y1,X2,Y2):-
   pos(X1,Y1), X2 is X1+1 , Y2 is Y1 , pos(X2,Y2).
mov(X1,Y1,X2,Y2):-
   pos(X1,Y1), X2 is X1 -1 , Y2 is Y1 , pos(X2,Y2).

path(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,Path) :-
   travel(pos(X1,Y1),pos(X2,Y2),[pos(X1,Y1)],Q),
   reverse(Q,Path).

travel(pos(X1,Y1),pos(X2,Y2),P,[pos(X2,Y2)|P]) :-
   mov(X1,Y1,X2,Y2).
travel(pos(X1,Y1),pos(X2,Y2),Visited,Path) :-
   mov(X1,Y1,X,Y),
   pos(X,Y) \== pos(X2,Y2), 
   \+member(pos(X,Y),Visited),
   travel(pos(X,Y),pos(X2,Y2),[pos(X,Y)|Visited],Path).
```

Comment: If you think you don't want to debug that mess, just imagine how we feel.

Comment: You need to explain further. What did you type in? What response did you expect? What error message(s) appeared, if any?

Comment: In `mov/4` you can remove all those goals for `pos/2` since in all other parts `pos/2` is just meant as a functor not as a predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some Prolog advice.

1. `member/2` is a built-in, you should not have to define it.
2. ISO negation is `\+`, not `not/1`.
3. For performance, `memberchk/2` beats `member/2`.
4. I see a lot of `foo(X,Y) :- X == Y, ...` in your code. It's much better if you just say `foo(X,X)` and save yourself the trouble of making explicit tests like this, unless you're going to do a conditional expression to avoid a choice point or something.
5. Lots of cuts in this code. Cuts and bugs tend to be great friends because the cut can undermine reasonable-looking code by preventing it from being executed.

If I had to solve this problem, I would want to separate the shortest-path logic from the grid traversal logic. You'll never be able to debug this, and even if you do, what you'll have is a one of those unreadable blocks of code that cannot be modified. It's clear that you have an explosion of terms because you're embedding the traversal logic in the path finding logic. Break them out into two separate steps and you will probably find that you get smaller pieces you can meaningfully test and debug. This is a good way of life with programming, regardless of the language: what would you do if you needed to change the grid structure or make the pathfinding more intelligent or complex? Keeping pieces granular always helps for managing change.

As for S.O. etiquette, this isn't great: you should talk about what doesn't work and what you've tried and you want to supply a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suspect in producing such a thing you'd probably solve the problem yourself.